# Upload image using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I am trying to upload an image using Django and there is no errors. But there is no file or directories inside the media folder.And except image field all other fields are updated in [table](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72063553/db.png).

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Player_Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_picture/%y%m%d', blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.BooleanField()
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from upload.models import Player_Profile
    def home(request):
        return render_to_response('upload/index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    def submit(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username=request.POST.get('username')
            email=request.POST.get('email')
            age=request.POST.get('age')
            pic=request.FILES.get('myfile')
            profile_obj=Player_Profile(profile_picture=pic,name=username, email=email,age=age).save()   
        return render_to_response('upload/welcome.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="/upload/submit/" method="POST" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        User Name :<input type="text" name="username" id="usrname"/><br/>
        Age :<input type="text" name="age" id="age"/><br/>
        Email :<input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
```

and inside settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/mridul/Desktop/Django/interim/pic/uploadpic/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and manually create media directory inside uploadpic directory.

Comment: (not really related to question but) you should also check if the form is_valid , no?

Comment: You can check out this tutorial - https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-upload-and-display-image-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not:

```
<form action="/upload/submit/" method="POST" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
```

it's

```
<form action="/upload/submit/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

i.e. [`enctype`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) not `encrypt`

As an aside, you should use a [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#form-objects) or [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to do this, it will [make your life much easier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).